# ReactJS // I would like to read more an article's description

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a API with ReactJS and I would like to read more an article's description like this =>

[image]

When I click on "Suite" (in english => read more) ALL descriptions from ALL the articles are now shown, but I would like to read more only the article I clicked on !

This is my code, do you know what I did wrong ? Thanks a lot !!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of sharing screenshots of your code, share the actual code because that helps people work with your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and how to make a proper [mre]. Don't post pictures of code. Copy the code into the question with formatting. Make a complete example, not just a few snippets. With that said, you need separate state for every description. Looks like you are using the same state for all of them. But since you haven't shown the complete code I'm only guessing from your description of what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `description` block and `isReadMoreShown` to a separate component. Right now there is one state that controls the behavior of all the children, instead, you want each component to have its own state.